# How a blow up changes the Canonical bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

lt $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ be a blowup a subvariety $V\subset$, where say both X and Y are smooth. Then what is the relation of $K_Y$ and $K_X$ ?

The case of surfaces is clear

What about higher dimension varieties?

In particular, Y is the blowup of a curve in a smooth threefold X.

Comment: This is written in lots of books. For example, see Griffiths and Harris. Anyway, the answer is $K_Y = f^*(K_X) + (c-1) E$ where $c$ is the codimension of $V$ in $X$ and $E$ is the exceptional divisor.